# Sorting is wrong when comparing long values

Tags: java, sorting, comparison, long-integer

I'm trying to sort long numbers in ASC but seems that the comparison is wrong. There is a sequence of correct digits, but from the 7th digit it all messes up. Can anyone advise why?

The classes:

```
public class MyTime {

    private long timeInMicroSeconds;

    public MyTime (long timeInMicroSeconds) {
        this.timeInMicroSeconds = timeInMicroSeconds;
    }
}

public class tester implements Comparator<MyTime> {

      public int compare(MyTime o1, MyTime o2) {
          return (int) ( (-1) * (o2.getTimeInMicroSeconds() - o1.getTimeInMicroSeconds()));
}
```

}

This is the main test with my numbers :

```
  MyTime t1 = new MyTime (1482072568710018L);
    MyTime  t2 = new MyTime (1482068966855246L);
    MyTime t3 = new MyTime (1482068967752058L);
    MyTime t4 = new MyTime (1482069164096129L);
    MyTime t5 = new MyTime (1482072704590983L);
    MyTime t6 = new MyTime (1482068963206124L);
    MyTime t7 = new MyTime (1482069164097807L);
    MyTime t8 = new MyTime (1482068962786004L);
    MyTime t9 = new MyTime (1482069034105390L);
    MyTime t10 = new MyTime (1482068979718112L);
    MyTime t11 = new MyTime (1482068963143736L);
    MyTime t12 = new MyTime (1482069164098280L);
    MyTime t13 = new MyTime (1482069029615872L);
    MyTime t14 = new MyTime (1482072704590408L);



    List<MyTime > n = new ArrayList<MyTime >();
    n.add(t1);
    n.add(t2);
    n.add(t3);
    n.add(t7);
    n.add(t11);
    n.add(t14);
    n.add(t10);
    n.add(t9);
    n.add(t6);
    n.add(t2);
    n.add(t4);
    n.add(t12);
    n.add(t13);
    n.add(t5);
    n.add(t8);



 //RUNNING THE SORT
   System.out.println("printing before : " );
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n.size() ; i ++)
    {
        System.out.println(n.get(i).getTimeInMicroSeconds());
    }

    Collections.sort(n, new tester());
    System.out.println("printing after : " );
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n.size() ; i ++)
    {
        System.out.println(n.get(i).getTimeInMicroSeconds());
    }
```

And this is the output:

```
    printing before : 
1482072568710018
1482068966855246
1482068967752058
1482069164097807
1482068963143736
1482072704590408
1482068979718112
1482069034105390
1482068963206124
1482068966855246
1482069164096129
1482069164098280
1482069029615872
1482072704590983
1482068962786004


printing after : 
1482072568710018
1482072704590408
1482072704590983
1482068962786004
1482068963143736
1482068963206124
1482068966855246
1482068966855246
1482068967752058
1482068979718112
1482069029615872
1482069034105390
1482069164096129
1482069164097807
1482069164098280
```

You can see that : `1482072568710018 < 1482072704590408 < 1482072704590983 > 1482068962786004`

any advise what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Why implement your own comparison here? There is already a "default" way to compare to long values, and that is [Long.compare()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare(long,%20long)). So simply change your method to call that static method:

```
public int compareTo(MyTime ...) {
  return Long.compare(o1.get...
}
```

Comment: No need to box them. [`Long.compare(long, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare(long,%20long)).

Comment: I wouldn't even bring `Long.compareTo()` into it: `Long.compare` is the correct approach. Boxing them is just inefficient, since [they are immediately unboxed](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Long.java#1233).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the cast in

> ```
>  return (int) ( (-1) * // ...
> ```

at that point you just trunk the upper 4 bytes from the long value getting a random bit being the sign indicator.

Therefore you get a random number.

As the other already stated you'd better use

```
Long.compare()
```

and if you have reverse the sort just switch the position of the compared numbers instead  of doing  `* -1`.

Comment: "Therefore you get a random number." I wouldn't say "random", as it's clearly not; I'd say that you end up doing a meaningless comparison.

Comment: You meant: "upper 4 bytes". An `int` is 4 bytes, a `long` is 8 bytes.

Comment: @AndyTurner "Therefore you get a random number." *I wouldn't say "random"* You're right, the resulting number deterministically depends on the original long, but from a users perspective, can you predict what you get when you apply a cast to a big long value? Therefore I think "random" is the right word for it.